# AJAX: PHP query doesn't refresh when called

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got a page where a table is supposed to reload when I click a link. The script works, and the variable is updated (I've tested that, see code), but the table doesn't reload with new data from the SQL query.

**Page**

```
<!-- SCRIPT START -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getResultat(str) {
if (str == "") {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getResultat.php?klasse2="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>
<!-- SCRIPT END -->

 <!-- LINK -->
<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick='javascript:getResultat("KSenior")'> KSenior </a>

 <!-- DATA get inserted here -->
 <div id="txtHint"><?php include("getResultat.php"); ?></div><br>
```

**getResultat.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['klasse2'])) {
$klasse2=$_REQUEST['klasse2'];
// Used to check if variable updates (for debuging only)
echo $klasse2; 
$klasse2= $_REQUEST['klasse2'];
} else {
$klasse2="MSenior";
// Used to check if variable updates (for debuging only)
echo $klasse2;
}

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM resultat 
WHERE resultat.klasse =  '$klasse2'
ORDER BY resultat.plassering ASC ";

// THIS SEND THE QUERY TO A CRUD
$selection= array("plassering", "navn","lagnavn", "tid_liten");  
$records_per_page=5;
$newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
$crud->dataview($newquery, $selection, $records_per_page, $sesong,  $bestetid['tid_ny']);

  ?>
```

I can post the CRUD if needed, but hopefully there is some common mistake I'm making?

When calling this page with a button the echo in the start reloads, but not the query.

Comment: Have you checked developers console? What is the `success` callback for js ajax?

Comment: The console dont send any errors,
 also I can see that the page is updated by the $echo I added for debuging.

Comment: Try using jQuery's ajax functions. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), just incase theres something wrong with your ajax. Have you tried var_dumping($_GET||$_REQUEST) just to see if anything is coming over?

Comment: $klasse2 is sent and updated, look at 
// Used to check if variable updates (for debuging only) in code

Comment: alert this value `xmlhttp.responseText` what you get ?

Comment: How do I alert it? Kind of new to AJAX

Comment: Your ajax is fine, check if your crud id returning the value intended or not echo that value, it should be good. Sorry I don't know crud.

Comment: probably you should just add an echo before the last line: echo $crud->dataview(...);